# Could not resolve dependency: peer vite@"^4.0.4" from vite-plugin-shopify@2.2.1

Tags: shopify, vite

I'm trying to use `vite-plugin-shopify` plugin on my shopify theme. My vite version is `5.0.7` but to work with the plugin it's saying me to downgrade it to `4.0.4`. Should I use --force option with my current vite version? Or, downgrade my vite version? Which will be appropriate option?

[image]

I tried the `npm i --force vite-plugin-shopify -D` and then it warned me.

[image]